# WPF binding ObservableCollection to ItemsControl - UI won't update

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, itemscontrol

fairly newbie here looking for a hand.

I'm trying to make a "game launcher" kind of thing, think like Steam, however when I add a new game to the file (currently just storing in a text file for ease until I have functionality working.

After adding the game, the UI won't refresh unless I switch the DataContext to a different view, and then back.

Here's the main 3 pages of code (without posting full thing, see [GitHub](https://github.com/pekempy/GameLauncher) for that): (forgive me if something is horrendously wrong)

**ListView.xaml**

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Game_Launcher.Views"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Game_Launcher.ViewModels"
         x:Class="Game_Launcher.Views.ListView"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModels:ListViewModel}"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.693,0.49">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- This section displays a card per game -->
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="7">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="gameListView" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,10,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="7" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=games, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <materialDesign:Card Margin="10 5 10 0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="80">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="GameIcon" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Icon, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                                <Label x:Name="GameTitle" Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="65,1,0,45" Width="175" Height="29" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <Label x:Name="GameGenre" Content="{Binding Genres, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="65,35,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.469" />
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="72,53,10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.469" FontSize="9">
                                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_Link">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="GameLink" Text="{Binding Link, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                                <Button x:Name="GameLauncher" Click="LaunchButton_OnClick" Tag="{Binding Path, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,16,6,19" Height="40" Width="40" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Gamepad" />
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </materialDesign:Card>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**ListView.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Game_Launcher.ViewModels;

namespace Game_Launcher.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ListView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ListView : UserControl
    {
        private ListViewModel lvm = new ListViewModel();

        public ListView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvm.refreshGames();
            gameListView.ItemsSource = lvm.games;
        }

        //Open web browser when link clicked
        private void Hyperlink_Link(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        }

        //Launch game path when clicked
        private void LaunchButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object link = ((Button)sender).Tag;
            string linkString = link.ToString().Trim();
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(linkString));
        }
    }
}
```

**ListViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Game_Launcher.ViewModels
{
    public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Game> games { get; set; }

        public void refreshGames()
        {
            games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
            if (File.Exists("./Resources/GamesList.txt"))
            {
                //Read file to gameFile
                string gameFile = "./Resources/GamesList.txt";
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(gameFile, true);
                //games is array containing all game info per item
                string[] gamesArr = File.ReadAllLines(gameFile);
                int numberOfGames = 0;
                string[] columns = new string[0];
                //columns is array containing each element of the game
                foreach (var item in gamesArr)
                {
                    columns = gamesArr[numberOfGames].Split('|');
                    Game g = new Game
                    {
                        Title = columns[0],
                        Genres = columns[1],
                        Path = columns[2],
                        Link = columns[3],
                        Icon = columns[4],
                        Poster = columns[5],
                        Banner = columns[6],
                    };

                    games.Add(new Game
                    {
                        Title = g.Title,
                        Genres = g.Genres,
                        Path = g.Path,
                        Link = g.Link,
                        Icon = g.Icon,
                        Poster = g.Poster,
                        Banner = g.Banner,
                    });
                    numberOfGames++;
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _title;
        private string _genres;
        private string _path;
        private string _link;
        private string _icon;
        private string _poster;
        private string _banner;

        public string Title { get { return _title; } set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(Title); } }
        public string Genres { get { return _genres; } set { _genres = value; OnPropertyChanged(Genres); } }
        public string Path { get { return _path; } set { _path = value; OnPropertyChanged(Path); } }
        public string Link { get { return _link; } set { _link = value; OnPropertyChanged(Link); } }
        public string Icon { get { return _icon; } set { _icon = value; OnPropertyChanged(Icon); } }
        public string Poster { get { return _poster; } set { _poster = value; OnPropertyChanged(Poster); } }
        public string Banner { get { return _banner; } set { _banner = value; OnPropertyChanged(Banner); } }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you add a new game? (And yes, you have lots of issues in your code.)

Comment: if you are just adding the game title to text file, then it is expected that your app doesn't update: it displays content of file at the moment of reading, not updated content

Comment: Games are added through a separate window (AddGameWindow) as it's a popup. After a game is added it calls refreshGames() so it would re-read the file. it successfully does this as 'games' is filled with the extra game that is added but the UI doesn't update

Answer (score 1):

Don't Create a new `ObservableCollection` instance each time you populate it. Just `Clear()` the existing items from the current instance, and then `Add()` your new set of items to it.

```
public ListViewModel()
{
    Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
}

...

public ObservableCollection<Game> Games { get; }

public void refreshGames()
{
    Games.Clear()

    ...

    // add items to Games collection here
}
```

Comment: I've changed code to this,and thank you, but UI still doesn't update when a new game is added (I've stepped through the code to confirm that _Games_ contains 5 games as opposed to the 4 I had when I first ran the code, so it is being populated into _Games_, it just isn't creating an extra material design card (xaml > ItemsControl binding)

Comment: Can you post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that demonstrates this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. There is so much wrong with the structure of your code that it's hard to know where to begin.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you have two separate view models going.  Remove these bits that deal with `ListViewModel`:

```
 private ListViewModel lvm = new ListViewModel();

    public ListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvm.refreshGames();
        gameListView.ItemsSource = lvm.games;
    }
```

You should be creating an instance of it in the XAML:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:ListViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```